# Directive template with Input + ng-model = magic?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I'm quite frustrated and apologize in advance for poorly formulated question.

I've created derictive for simple list editing:

```
angular.module('myApp').
    directive('variableList', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            templateUrl: 'variableList.html',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                value: '='
            },
            controller: [
                '$scope', '$element', '$attrs', '$transclude',
                function($scope) {
                    $scope.removeListItem = function (index) {
                        $scope.value.splice(index, 1);
                    };
                    $scope.addListItem = function () {
                        $scope.value.push($scope.nextListItem);
                        $scope.nextListItem = null;
                    };
                }
            ]
        };
    });
```

and template

```
<div class="variable-list">
    <div class="variable-list-items">
        <div class="row collapse variable-list-item" ng-repeat="(index, val) in value">
            <div class="small-11 columns variable-list-item-value">
                <input type="text" ng-model="val" />
            </div>
            <div class="small-1 columns">
                <button class="button alert prefix no-margin icon-minus"
                        ng-click="removeListItem(index)"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row collapse variable-list-controls">
        <div class="small-11 columns">
            <input type="text" ng-model="nextListItem" />
        </div>
        <div class="small-1 columns">
            <button ng-class="{disabled: !nextListItem}"
                    ng-click="addListItem()"
                    class="button success prefix no-margin icon-plus"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the important part of template if

```
<input type="text" ng-model="val" />
```

In the end I have quite working ui
[image]

**But inputs for existings items doesnt work!** Nothing happen when I try to edit them. Input for new item, add and remove buttons works as intended.

Any ideas?

**Edit**
I've tried to bind model like this

```
<input type="text" ng-model="value[key]" />
```

I was able to edit input but it caused even more magic, after first keypress input loses focus.

Answer (score 0):

Found answer here https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1267

> Basically you have to have a . in ng-model or the revers data binding does not work on primitives.